# I can't see my new layout

Tags: android, layout

I make a new layout and i can't setContentView(R.layout.paintlinglayout) . Why ?
Here is a picture : http://postimg.org/image/s5a2e60k1/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've imported `android.R` instead of `[your-package-name].R`.

Comment: maybe you can help me and here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033736/android-simple-draw . Why when i try to make a C , i see like a ball , the mX and mY don't change in the function touch_move